# How to reset the input css to the defaults in Bootstrap 3.2

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I changed the default border css for a specific input element in bootstrap 3.2 to be green by using the following code:

```
$('#' + fieldID).css({
    'border-color': '#00b300', 
    'border-width': '1px', 
    'box-shadow': 'none', 
    'outline': 'none', 
    '-webkit-box-shadow': 'none'
});
```

where fieldID is the name of the input field

Now in a specific scenario, I would like to reset this field to the default behaviour/styling.

I managed to get it to look like a default focused in field by using the following:

```
$('#' + fieldID).css({
    'border-color': '#9ecaed', 
    'border-width': '1px', 
    'box-shadow': '0 0 10px #9ecaed',  
    '-webkit-box-shadow': '0 0 10px #9ecaed',
    'outline': 'none'
});
```

this however does not restore the default behavior where the default field has a grey border and focused one has blue (as shown below)

[image]

[image]

Please guide me if there is a way to restore normal behavior, I have even tried cloning the element in jQuery, but that copies the styling and thus in vain.

Thanks for reading this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply we can do like this

```
<style>
    .myClass {
            border-color:#9ecaed;
            border-width: 1px;
            box-shadow: 0 0 10px #9ecaed;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #9ecaed;
            outline:none;
     }

</style>
```

jquery be . if you add the class like this

```
$('#'+fieldID).addClass("myClass");
```

reset you want to remove the class

```
$('#'+fieldID).removeClass("myClass");
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not style that via jQuery. Create new CSS class, for example `default-input` and in your jQuery, you will do this to set default:

```
$('#'+fieldID).addClass('default-input');
```

and to reset to bootstrap-default:

```
$('#'+fieldID).removeClass('default-input');
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, however Sudarshan gave a similar answer a minute  before you, both were right. Appreciate the help.